# The CE agreement for processing Mastercard is not accepted

Tags: paypal

Using paypal sandbox account when i m making a transaction with new 3-D secure fields it return with error

The CE agreement for processing Mastercard is not accepted.

Where do i accept CE agreement for my sandbox account?

in sandbox.paypal.com there are almost links are not working eg clicking **Legal Agreement** no page found error is being displayed

if any one has any experience about it

I will be thank ful

Leo

Answer (score 2):

I did not receive any answer on this. but fortunately Paypal technical support replied to me. Thank God!

According to their email.

Before being able to process Website Payments Pro API transactions, you will need to first accept the billing agreement.

To make the change please sign in to developer central, then the relevant account

On the top right of the page you'll see a 'Getting Started' section. You'll see a link for either 'Submit Application' or 'Accept Billing Agreement' and follow the on-screen steps. (Tick both optional services on the 'Products and optional services' page)
Once you are at the Billing agreement page. Click agree and Pro functionality will be enabled on your account.
There is a tutorial video on the following link: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/ppdts.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=755

---

In short you just need to accept CE agreement in order to use **3D-secure** features with **Payment-Pro**.

Many thanks to all of the viewer who at-least viewed the post.

Regards,
Waqas Zamir,
Software Developer, MCP